# How to install the libxcb-cursor.so.0 library?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, libraries, shared-library

Looking to install the [feather](https://docs.featherwallet.org/guides/linux) wallet for Monero but am missing a shared library as below:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ wget https://featherwallet.org/files/releases/linux/feather-2.4.9-linux.zip
--2023-06-06 09:11:14--  https://featherwallet.org/files/releases/linux/feather-2.4.9-linux.zip
Resolving featherwallet.org (featherwallet.org)... 89.147.108.182
Connecting to featherwallet.org (featherwallet.org)|89.147.108.182|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 25876327 (25M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘feather-2.4.9-linux.zip’

feather-2.4.9-linux.zip                          77%[=============================================================================>                        ]  19.07M  26.9KB/s    eta 4feather-2.4.9-linux.zip                       100%[================================================================================================>]  24.68M  46.4KB/s    in 16m 41s 

2023-06-06 09:27:58 (25.3 KB/s) - ‘feather-2.4.9-linux.zip’ saved [25876327/25876327]

nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ ll
total 25284
drwxr-xr-x  2 nicholas nicholas     4096 Jun  6 09:11 ./
drwxr-x--- 19 nicholas nicholas     4096 Jun  6 09:27 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 nicholas nicholas 25876327 May 24 17:05 feather-2.4.9-linux.zip
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ unzip feather-2.4.9-linux.zip 
Archive:  feather-2.4.9-linux.zip
  inflating: feather-2.4.9           
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ ll
total 88332
drwxr-xr-x  2 nicholas nicholas     4096 Jun  6 09:28 ./
drwxr-x--- 19 nicholas nicholas     4096 Jun  6 09:27 ../
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nicholas nicholas 64560224 Feb 12 15:26 feather-2.4.9*
-rw-rw-r--  1 nicholas nicholas 25876327 May 24 17:05 feather-2.4.9-linux.zip
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ ./feather-2.4.9 
./feather-2.4.9: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-cursor.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$
```

I was expecting to see different files and instructions for installing this package, but at the moment, am just dealing with this error.

```
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libxcb-xinerama0 is already the newest version (1.15-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install libxcb-xinput0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libxcb-xinput0 is already the newest version (1.15-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ ./feather-2.4.9 
./feather-2.4.9: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-cursor.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$
```

At the moment, just looking to [install](https://askubuntu.com/q/1194024/847449) the requisite library.

*Perhaps need to install the xcb-util-cursor package?*

Comment: You installed the wrong library. It's looking for `libxcb-cursor.so.0` which is in the `libxcb-cursor0` package (hence the name). So `apt install libxcb-cursor0` would have sorted it. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lunar&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libxcb-cursor.so.0

Comment: this was already installed @popey with still the same error, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I was just downloading the wrong feather wallet file:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads/monero$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads/monero$ wget https://featherwallet.org/files/releases/linux-appimage/feather-2.4.9.AppImage
--2023-06-06 09:53:47--  https://featherwallet.org/files/releases/linux-appimage/feather-2.4.9.AppImage
Resolving featherwallet.org (featherwallet.org)... 89.147.108.182
Connecting to featherwallet.org (featherwallet.org)|89.147.108.182|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 25420024 (24M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘feather-2.4.9.AppImage’

feather-2.4.9.AppImage                        100%[================================================================================================>]  24.24M   514KB/s    in 50s     

2023-06-06 09:54:39 (492 KB/s) - ‘feather-2.4.9.AppImage’ saved [25420024/25420024]

nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads/monero$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads/monero$ ll
total 24836
drwxrwxr-x 2 nicholas nicholas     4096 Jun  6 09:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 nicholas nicholas     4096 Jun  6 09:53 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nicholas nicholas 25420024 May 24 17:01 feather-2.4.9.AppImage
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads/monero$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads/monero$ chmod a+x feather-2.4.9.AppImage 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads/monero$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads/monero$ ll
total 24836
drwxrwxr-x 2 nicholas nicholas     4096 Jun  6 09:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 nicholas nicholas     4096 Jun  6 09:53 ../
-rwxrwxr-x 1 nicholas nicholas 25420024 May 24 17:01 feather-2.4.9.AppImage*
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads/monero$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads/monero$ ./feather-2.4.9.AppImage 
/tmp/.mount_feathe9SVX84
"Creating directory: /home/nicholas/.config/feather"
"Creating directory: /home/nicholas/.config/feather/tor"
"Creating directory: /home/nicholas/.config/feather/tor/data"
Logging is disabled
Feather: 2.4.9
Mode: Mainnet
Qt: 6.5.0
SSL: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
SSL build: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
Tor version: 0.4.7.13
[2023-06-06 09:55:22 D] (:0) wallet .keys search initiated
```

which seems to run fine.  Still don't know how to install that specific library, however.  That being said, I was only asking about the library in the context of launching this wallet.